# ubuntu 16.04-AMD Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230 - black screen after boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Please bear with me as This is the last place to resolve the as I have tried different resources available for the problem already, but with no effect.Long story short, Ubuntu 16.04 was working fine for a long time but since recently, It is showing up the black screen after boot.By blank screen, I mean:-

**The Problem**:-

After Boot (i.e. after purple screen),

1. There is no mouse pointer.
2. A cursor blinks for a few seconds and screen goes 100% black but still lit, and then after another few seconds, it goes completely dark as if it is turned off.
3. I wait and then switch to the command-line screen or tty1 to get the logs.

**What I have done yet**:-

1. I have updated my system, with `oibaf-drivers` but still no help. `fglrx` is officially deprecated for Ubuntu 16.04 and `amdgpu-pro` provided by AMD does not support AMD graphic card of my system.Currently, the system is using(I don't know whether it is perfectly working or not) `radeon driver` (The OSS driver for AMD). For more info, here are the specs of GPU on my system:-

   Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]

   VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
2. `dmesg | grep -i radeon` shows no error during boot-up.
3. If running the system in `nomodeset`, which is resulting in highly poor graphics performance. It is much deflected compared to ideal. The fan is running crazy in `nomodeset`. The system is using `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)` to render graphics.
4. If not running the system in `nomodeset` but using `startX` in tty1, the systemUI restarts again but `mouse pointer turns to a cross` and only folders present on my desktop are visible, but no wallpaper can be seen, no side-dock, no launcher (after the click) and no status bar.The desktop is completely absent though desktop folders are visible and can be opened.

I am open for any solution/fix. I have referred [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) but it is of not much help. It asks to install proprietary drivers. In the case of  AMD, it easily discards old models hence it is difficult to find supported drivers. Alternatives have been tried out, but it is not solving the problem.

**Edit 1**:- Properitry drivers are available for the GPU, but after installation system fails to boot.The only option is to uninstall it.